# Magento not executing my module install script

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I am trying to create a local module. Here regarding this there are lot of question. I have almost all of them followed. But it is never working.

Atlast I followed this: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-6.html

But this is als not working. Here is my structure:

app/code/local/Mycompany/Hello/Model/Resource/Setup.php

```
<?php
class Mycompany_Hello_Model_Resource_Setup extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup {
```

}

in app/code/local/Mycompany/Hello/sql/mycompany_hello_setup/install-0.1.0.php

```
<?php
    echo 'Running This test: '.get_class($this)."\n <br /> \n";
    die("Exit for now");
```

app/code/local/Mycompany/Hello/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Hello>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mycompany_Hello>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <hello>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mycompany_Hello</module>
                    <frontName>hello</frontName>
                </args>
            </hello>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <Mycompany_Hello_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Mycompany_Hello</module>
                    <class>Mycompany_Hello_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </Mycomapny_Hello_setup> 
    </resources> 
</global>
```

Here the only issue I am facing is it never executes install script.
My approches till now:

Renamed app/code/local/Mycompany/Hello/sql/mycompany_hello_setup/install-0.1.0.php to following names on each attempt **app/code/local/Mycompany/Hello/sql/hello_setup/install-0.1.0.php**,
**app/code/local/Mycompany/Hello/sql/hello_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php**, **app/code/local/Mycompany/Hello/sql/mycompany_hello_setup/install-0.1.0.php**,
**app/code/local/Mycompany/Hello/sql/Mycompany_hello_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php**

During every attempt I flush cache and delete the entry from core_resources table.

All my file permisson is 777 (for debugging purpose, later I will change it to 755). Actaully I placed a debugging code in install. Once it executed, I will replace this with my actual installer script.

But it seems something, I am missing something, as a result it is not working.

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri actually there is no duplicate file mysql4-install. In every attempt I just rename that.

Comment: I am not telling you are creating duplicate file, I am saying it may be same qust. You can check the answer in that qst. It looks similar to me.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri Sorry, I did not noticed the top. I am checking it, will update it. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XML node

```
        <Mycompany_Hello_setup>
```

must match the path

```
sql/mycompany_hello_setup/install-0.1.0.php
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It looks like you got the capitalization wrong.

Comment: Thank you, This is the case I am facing. Thank you very much for your help. Actually I am a magento beginer. I am very sorry for this silly mistake.

Comment: Don't worry, it's easy to fall into traps like this at the beginning, you'll learn all these conventions eventually.

Answer (score 1):

check your table name core_resource and find of mycompany_hello_setup if is version and data value is => 0.1.0 either delete this entry or just reduce this value like 0.0.1 something like that then refresh your magento cache your script should b executed

Comment: To trigger `install`, you have to delete it. Otherwise Magento only looks for `upgrade` scripts.